# How to disable the creation of temp table after query exceution

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have scenario where once I execute a query a temp table will be created and I will be iterating through that temp table only to fetch data based on certain page size. Now each time I query that temp table another temp table is created I don't want that is there any mechanism to disable it from Query Job Configuration in java

I want temp table creation disabled based on query job config